# JS function inside function:

Tags: javascript, function, scope

Can i do smth like this?

```
function calltime(gmt,ajaxfile){
    //do something with vars gmt & ajaxfile...

    function (){
        alert(gmt+ajaxfile); 
    }
}
```

as you may notice I want the inner function without a name to use arguments of a parent without sending them directly as arguments, Is it possible or is there the other way (without creating completely separate function)?

Comment: Inner functions can access the scope of outer functions.

Comment: Thank you! If i change this vars inside outer fn which data the inner will get? changed or 'default'?

Comment: "Exception: SyntaxError: function statement requires a name". Why don't you just try your example before posting it?

Comment: This JS is invalid. You cannot have a function without a name that isn't assigned to a variable or wrapped in brackets. You could either do `(function(){...})` which would execute it immediately (although this is a little pointless) or you should name it and call it elsewhere. Try paste it in your console, this doesn't work.

Comment: What others saying is that you have what appears to be a [*function declaration*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions) without the required name. So give it a name to make it a valid declaration (e.g. `function myFunc(){...}`), or use syntax that makes it a function expression (e.g. `var myFunc = function(){...}` or `(function(){...}())`).

Comment: @AndrewBro were you able to find the answer you were looking for?  Go ahead and select an answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to get it to work.  These methods will have self invoking inside.  If you don't want them to invoke when calling `calltime`, then you can look at @harry's answer, which returns the inner function instead of invoking it.

```
var calltime = function(gmt, ajaxfile) {
  (function (g, a){ 
    alert(g + a); 
  })(gmt, ajaxfile);
};

calltime('Hello ', 'there');
```

But if you really don't want to specify arguments, you can just straight up do this:

```
var calltime = function(gmt, ajaxfile) {   
  (function (){ 
    alert(gmt + ajaxfile); 
  })();
};

calltime('Hello ', 'there');
```

The inside function will self invoke itself. You can copy and paste this into chrome inspector to test.

And one more, since we're talking about self invocation, might as well invoke everything about your question!

```
(function calltime(gmt, ajaxfile) {   
  (function (){ 
    alert(gmt + ajaxfile); 
  })();
})('Hello ', 'there');
```

Edit: one more version that takes in numerous arguments.

```
var calltime = function () {
  (function () { 
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    alert(args.join(' ')); // outputs 'hello there friend'
  }).apply(this, arguments);
}; 

calltime('hello', 'there', 'friend');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  function calltime(gmt,ajaxfile){
  //do something with vars gmt & ajaxfile...

     return  function (){
        alert(gmt+ajaxfile); 
    }
}
 //you can call like this
 calltime('Hello', 'there')();

 //you can call like this also
 var callit = calltime('Hello', 'there');
 callit();
```

If you are creating a function inside a function you are creating a clouser. so that you can access that inner function later and you can use outer function arguments and variables(scope) in the inner functions whenever you want. so you no need to pass argument to the inner function.

Answer (score 0):

```
function calltime(gmt,ajaxfile){
    //do something with vars gmt & ajaxfile...

      var a = function (){
       alert(gmt+ajaxfile); 
         }
    }
    calltime('a','b');
```

You can do it like so.

Comment: That doesn't do anything when running calltime().  The `a` function will not be invoked.

Comment: You want to call function "a" from outside "calltime" that's not possible, is that what you want?